# Fill Series by common value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, fill

I would like to fill NaN values in Pandas DataFrame using the common value. I check the common value in certain Series using function describe.
How can I fill NaN value using this common value ?

Comment: Can you provide and example?

Comment: You mean by the `mode`?

Comment: for example I have DataFrame like this: df = pd.DataFrame("Value": {"S", "S", "S", NaN, NaN, "P"}) as you can see "S" is the most common value and I want to fill NaN using "S" how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you're probably searching for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Value": ["S", "S", "S", np.nan, np.nan, "P"]})

print(df.fillna(df['Value'].value_counts().index[0]))
```

This fill `NaNs` with most common value:

```
  Value
0     S
1     S
2     S
3     S
4     S
5     P
```

Comment: And how can I check whether it works when I have many many rows ?

Comment: @Adrian I don't understand. This will change all `NaN` with most common value from the column `Value`. In every row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "common value" but using df.fillna() can replace NaN values in your Series. Check the documentation here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna

Comment: for example I have DataFrame like this: df = pd.DataFrame("Value": {"S", "S", "S", NaN, NaN, "P"}) as you can see "S" is the most common value and I want to fill NaN using "S" how can I do it ?